# Need drivers for Matrox G400

Tags: drivers, graphics, matrox

I need Ubuntu 11.04 drivers for a Matrox G400.

I put the video card in and nothing came up on the screen, so I guess there are no drivers of any kind for Ubuntu 11.04.

So do I have to load the drivers first using my old card, if so, how do I do it?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Does it recognize your new card

```
lspci | grep VGA
```

Have you run

```
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then checked in Additional Drivers?

Comment: I ran sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-mga and it said it was already the latest version. so were do I put it so the matrx g400 will reconise it, as it is now when I put the g400 card in nothing come up on the screen except the boot amd bios page then it goes blank.

Comment: Its not in additional drivers

Comment: once booted can you get to TTY1 with ctrl+alt+F1 and try the commands there?

Answer (score 0):

Checked in [Matrox's website for drivers](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/support/drivers/) and as assumed they have left out the legacy drivers.

You can do two things

- Try using one of g450 series, see if it resolves the issue.
- or mail the authority asking, that you need an old driver.

Comment: What do you mean? There are legacy [binary drivers](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/support/drivers/download/?id=143) on that site.

Comment: There isn't Matrox g440 driver. G-Series starts with G450.

Comment: G-series starts at G400 however a G440 graphics card does not  actually exist. If you read the main text it specifies G400. There is a link on that site called [Legacy (Older) Drivers](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/support/drivers/latest/).

Comment: @cas Matrox G440 exists. But its kinda weird that they have, G100, G200, G400 even a G450(legacy!). But no G440.

Comment: I have never heard or seen of a G440 and I have used many Matrox cards over the years.

Comment: That G400 binary driver is from 2006, and IIRC it was outdated even then (I had a G400 until 2006).

Answer (score 0):

Matrox G400 should have working open source drivers supplied with x.org. It may be that the correct driver just doesn't get loaded automatically. This happens with some older intel graphics chips too.

Try putting this into /etc/X11/xorg.conf

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "Configured Video Device"
    Driver "mga"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "Configured Monitor"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Default Screen"
    Monitor "Configured Monitor"
    Device "Configured Video Device"
EndSection
```